# Updating ca-certificates on mac os

Tags: macos, openssl, certificate, ca

I am not completely familiar under the mac os environment, but I am trying to update the ca-certificates following the instructions on this page to solve an error: https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/WEBAPI/Web-API+Troubleshooting point 3.1.2.3.

I created the file `~/new-root-certificate.crt` and then I ran:

```
alert:~ Me$ sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ~/new-root-certificate.crt
SecCertificateCreateFromData: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.
Error reading file /Users/Gino/new-root-certificate.crt
```

Who do I bypass this error?

Comment: find the answer to this?